# Sharepoint 2010 databinding with list custom columns

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have custom SPlist with some fields that I'd like to bind to a repeater inside a visual web part. I can't use a SPDataSource as I have to do some custom stuff with the list before binding.

How do I bind a custom column in this way? When I use Eval on a custom column I get an error

If I do a test with the datasource it works again Eval("HoursOfOperation"):

```
<SharePoint:SPDataSource runat="server" ID="data" DataSourceMode="List" 
  SelectCommand="<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='CBC'/><Value Type='Boolean'>0</Value></Eq></Where>">
  <SelectParameters>
      <asp:Parameter Name="WebUrl" DefaultValue="/" />
      <asp:Parameter Name="ListName" DefaultValue="Locations" />
  </SelectParameters>
</SharePoint:SPDataSource>
```

But, if I use the following code I get an error **DataBinding: 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem' does not contain a property with the name 'HoursOfOperation'.**

```
  SPSite site = SPContext.Current.Site;
  SPWeb web = site.RootWeb;

  SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
  query.ViewFieldsOnly = true;
  query.Query = string.Concat(
                                "<Where><Eq>",
                                    "<FieldRef Name='CBC'/>",
                                    "<Value Type='Boolean'>0</Value>",
                                "</Eq></Where>"
                                );

  SPList list = web.Lists["Locations"];
  SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);

  rp.DataSource = list;
  rp.DataBind();
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found this myself:

For non-indexed properties you need to cast the dataitem to a SPListItem and get the property by name.

```
<%# ((SPListItem)Container.DataItem)["HoursOfOperation"] %>
```